# リストをfor文で代入したい

Tags: r

6つの既存のリストを `list[1],list[2],list[3],list[4],list[5],list[6]` というような形で `for` 文で代入したいのですが、どうすればいいかわかりません。

ベクトルで `for` 文を用いて、`f[1],f[2],f[3],f[4],f[5],f[6]` に対して代入するときは、
以下のようになるのはわかるのですが、リストを同じようにするとうまく行きません。

どなたかおしえて頂けますでしょうか。

```
f<-NULL

for(i in 1:6){
    f[i]<- i
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(質問の趣旨の確認はコメントで書くルールらしいですが, 信用度が足りず書き込めないため回答に含めます)

> 6つの既存のリストを `list[1],list[2],list[3],list[4],list[5],list[6]` というような形で

> リストを同じようにする

というのが具体的にどういう操作なのか不明瞭なので確認ですが, `list` と言う名前の新しいリストの中にさらに6つのリスト, 例えば `li1, ... li6`  を入れたいということですか? この例のように規則のある名前が付いているのなら, `get()` を使うことでできます.

```
li1 <- list(name = "リスト1です")
li2 <- list(name = "リスト2です")
li3 <- list(name = "リスト3です")
li4 <- list(name = "リスト4です")
li5 <- list(name = "リスト5です")
li6 <- list(name = "リスト6です")

list <- list()
for(i in 1:6){
  list[[i]] <- get(paste0("li", i))
}
class(list) # リスト型になっていることを確認

str(list) # 要素もリストになっていることを確認
```